# When timeline is occur

Tags: discussion, meta

The timeline is occur at stackoverflow for all question/anwser.
We can see who is vote up or down their question.
This is neccessory or privacy?
[image: Screen]

Comment: The clock icon in the sidebar was added very recently, but it links to a page that has always been visible. It is *not* possible to see who downvoted (or upvoted) your post in the timeline view. There are no privacy concerns here.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a summary of what you can already find on the page, just grouped together by date. It does not show who actually up-voted or down-voted the question or answer. For example, you now have a downvote on this question (not by me), but you can't see who it is in the history. So it isn't a privacy concern, if that was your question.

Comment: Oh, "I cannot see who is downvote.", "and when this option is appeared?"